# Free annotation software where I can review web pages and save a PDF?

Tags: gratis, web-apps, pdf, note-taking

Just like Microsoft Word allows you to review and annotate documents, I'm looking for something similar for web pages - preferably a browser plugin. I should be able to highlight text (not just "draw on the page freely") in web pages and add annotations, then save a PDF with the results so that I can email it to the document author. This will allow me to suggest multiple modifications to a document at once while collaborating with my team, who publishes most of their documentation on the company intranet as web pages. Again, exactly the same as Word's reviewing feature.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pastel](https://usepastel.com/how-it-works)

Better than saving a PDF and emailing, Pastel creates a collaborative "canvas" overlay of the entire site, and allows everyone to comment, chat, and resolve issues.

- Highlight text
- Add annotations
- No sign-in required for collaborators: just email them the link
- Suggest multiple modifications at once
- Collaborate with your team
- Discussion
- Track issues